# Determining Rows Inserted After A Period of Time

Tags: linq-to-entities, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

I have a list of students in a SQL CE 4.0 database. Each one has an insert time associated with the student. Here is the context setup.

```
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime InsertTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class StudentContext : DbContext
    {
        public StudentContext()
            : base("StudentContext")
        { }
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

Inserting a new student works great as shown below:

```
    static void AddStudent(string name)
    {
        using (var db = new StudentContext())
        {
            var s = new Student()
            {
                Name = name,
                InsertTime = DateTime.Now
            };
            db.Students.Add(s);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

The issue I am running into is that when I want to DELETE entries from the database after a given amount of time, using the linq to entities to query for entries that are older than a period of time fails.  Below is my first attempt to look for entries older than 30 seconds.

```
        var student = (from x in db.Students
                       where x.Name == name
                       &&  x.InsertTime.AddSeconds(30) < DateTime.Now 
                       select x).ToList();
```

This fails with the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime
>   AddSeconds

Ok so apparently I need something linq will understand. Looking though StackOverflow I was able to find a method called EntityFunctions and modified my code as follows:

```
System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.AddSeconds(x.InsertTime, 30) < DateTime.Now
```

This also fails with the following error:

> The function is not recognized by SQL Server Compact. [ Name of
>   function = ADDSECONDS...

Great, after more digging I found that the EntityFunctions only work with the SQL Provider, and not the SQL CE 4.0 provider. Perfect!

The only thing I could come up with was getting the list of entries and then filtering that collection once again.

```
  var student = (from x in db.Students
                               where x.Name == name  
                               select x).ToList();

  var filteredStudent = student.Where(s => s.InsertTime.AddSeconds(30) < DateTime.Now).ToList();
```

This does work and the correct data is now available for deletion. However, the query could potentially return a large set of data, only to be filtered down to a couple of entries. The [ADDDATE()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174077.aspx) is supported by Sql Compact CE 4.0.  Is there any way I could write my own extension to the Linq to entities that would allow me to utilize the function? Can you think of another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try something like this?  This should take the time manipulation out of the linq.

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-30)

var student = (from x in db.Students
              where x.Name == name &&  x.InsertTime < time
              select x).ToList();
```